Limit of $(1+1)(1+1/2)(1+1/4)\dots $
I am trying to find the limit of :
$$\prod_{i=0}^\infty (1+\frac{1}{2^i})$$
Numerically, I can see that this converges to some limit $L<5$, but I'm not able to find the explicit expression of $L$. Even showing that the product is bounded above by $5$ seems challenging.
Any idea? It's possible that $L$ does not have a simple expression.. but I'm just curious.

See this answer here for a succinct explanation of the answer and why it likely can't be simplified (multiply it by $2$ in your case).

This question is perfectly reasonable and should not be closed for not having enough context. Rather, it should be closed for being a duplicate of the above question.

@Smiley1000 I originally flagged it as a duplicate a couple of minutes before it was closed for lacking context, but the close votes won before my duplicate flag was checked. Same thing happened with another question just a few minutes ago. I don't blame anyone, I've just been deleting the automatic message from the duplicate flag and posting a kinder one directing the OP to the older question.
